# Python - binary to num and num to binary - Wrong Output

Tags: python-3.x, io, binary

While working on some complex project, I came across an interesting bug:

Code reads the file, converts binary to integers, writes to the file.
Other fellow reads this file and converts integers to binary and writes to a file.

Ideally, input file and converted files should be same. But that is not happening.

Pl find the code below:

```
# read file -> convert to binary -> binary to num -> write file

def bits(f):
    byte = (ord(b) for b in f.read())
    for b in byte:
        bstr = []
        for i in range(8):
            bstr.append( (b >> i) & 1)
        yield bstr 
def binaryToNum(S):
    bits = len(S)
    if (S==''): return 0
    elif (S[0] == '0'): return binaryToNum(S[1:])
    elif (S[0] == '1'): return ((2**(bits-1))) + binaryToNum(S[1:])

bstr = []
for b in bits(open('input_test', 'r')):
    bstr.append(b)
dstr = ''
for i in bstr:
    b_num = str(binaryToNum(''.join(str(e) for e in i))).zfill(6)
    dstr = dstr + b_num

ter = open('im1', 'w')
for item in dstr:
    ter.write(item)
ter.close()
```

This part seems correct, I checked manually for a-z, A-Z and 0-9

The code on other machine does this:

```
def readDecDataFromFile(filename):
    data = []
    with open(filename) as f:
        data = data + f.readlines()
    chunks, chunk_size = len(data[0]), 6
    return [ data[0][i:i+chunk_size] for i in range(0, chunks, chunk_size) ]

def numToBinary(N):
        return str(int(bin(int(N))[2:]))

ddata = readDecDataFromFile('im1')
bytes = []
for d in ddata:
    bits = numToBinary(d)
    bytes.append(int(bits[::-1], 2).to_bytes(1, 'little'))
f = open('orig_input', 'wb')
for b in bytes:
    f.write(b)
f.close()
```

And here is the output:

```
input_test: my name is XYZ
orig_input: my7ameisY-
```

bytes list in last code yields: 
`[b'm', b'y', b'\x01', b'7', b'a', b'm', b'e', b'\x01', b'i', b's', b'\x01', b'\x0b', b'Y', b'-', b'\x05']`

What could be the potential error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

two modifications are required.

1. while reading the bits, current order is little endian. To convert it,

   ```
   reversed(range(8))
   ```

   should be used in `bits` function.
2. While converting from bits to bytes at the time of writing, bit string is reversed. That is not needed. So Code changes from

   ```
   bytes.append(int(bits[::-1], 2).to_bytes(1, 'little'))
   ```

   To

   ```
   bytes.append(int(bits, 2).to_bytes(1, 'little'))
   ```